# unable to determine what cmake generator to use-VS Code-Windows 10

Tags: c++, c++17

while compiling cpp files in vs code in windows 10 PC, after giving "cmake:debug" I get error like this "unable to determine what cmake generator to use.please install or configure a preferred generator or update settings.json, your kit configuration or path variable"
how to solve the error

Comment: Did you install cmake and set it up in your project?

Comment: I installed cmake and also added it's path to system environment variable.

Comment: Any luck with this issue? Were you able to solve the problem?

Comment: For correct cmake generation of mingw I use ninja. You should add ninja path to system environment variable or just to copy ninja.exe to bin folder witch you already added or install it with help pacman.

Comment: Use the `Ninja` generator whenever you can. `Ninja` is significantly faster than any of the other options and it's trivial to install and use.

Answer (score 11):

Firstly check the system.

1. Install MINGW https://www.msys2.org/
2. Install gcc, g++, gdb, and cmake using pacman.

   pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc

   pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gdb

   pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-cmake
3. Check installation:

   gcc --version

   g++ --version

   gdb --version
4. Edit environment variables for your account (PATH)

   C:\msys64\mingw64\bin

For cmake project on Vscode:

1. Create a cmake project: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cmake-linux#_create-a-cmake-project
2. Choose the Kit (Toolchain) which was installed before
3. Set cmake.cmakePath (If you installed with pacman, the path should be same as gcc/g++.

   "cmake.cmakePath": "C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\cmake.exe"
4. Reset VScode: Ctrl+shift+P and type "CMake:Reset CMake Tools for Extension State"
5. Configure project: Ctrl+shift+P and type "CMake: Configure". You will see "built" directory and generated files.

Comment: Very good and quick guide. I think it should be in official vscode docs :)

Comment: I found that I also needed to select "let cmake choose which kits to use" after running reset. If you choose the VS Code selected one it still remains broken.

Answer (score 6):

If you have install cmake, setted up your project and you added it's path, try this Ctrl+shift+P and Type "cmake:reset cmake tools for extension state" and press enter.

At least that works for me.