# 'Making' a project with cmake. Running into an error with regards to my inclusion of <filesystem>

Tags: c++, cmake, c++17, mingw32

I apologise for any inaccurate language - I'm very new to writing in c++ and using cmake

I'm using the cmake gui to do the generation. My generator is MinGW. The generation goes fine but when I try to run `mingw32-make` in the build directory (in terminal) I get the error message shown below:

```
anamorph_video_commandline.cpp:6:22: fatal error: filesystem: No such file or directory
 #include <filesystem>
                      ^
```

This is what my CMakeLists.txt looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26.0)
project(anamorph_movie)

# Set the C++ standard to C++17
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)


# include the vcg library
include_directories(./lib/vcglib-main/)
# include the eigen library
include_directories(./lib/vcglib-main/eigenlib)


# Add your executable and source files here
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} anamorph_video_commandline.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} stdc++fs)
```

I've tried using `<experimental/filesystem>` in my .cpp and get the same error message except it says

```
anamorph_video_commandline.cpp:6:22: fatal error: filesystem: No such file or directory
 #include <experimental/filesystem>
```

MinGW and cmake were both installed a couple days ago so I think its unlikely that its to do with the version.

As you can see from my CMakeLists.txt I also tried using: `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} stdc++fs)` per the recommendation of something I found online, also no luck.

Comment: what do you mean by "My generator is MinGW"?

Comment: There isn't a single thing called "mingw". It's possible that you've installed a version of it without `<filesystem>` support. Uninstall it and reinstall from [MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075), that's probably the best MinGW version out there as of now.

Comment: When specifying the generator for the project using the gui I select MinGW Makefiles. In cmd it looks like `cmake .. -G "MinGW Makefiles"`.
I also suspected that I installed a version without <filesystem> support. I'll try following the stuff from the link and report back.

Comment: Report - installed msys following the advice in these links:
https://www.msys2.org
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70197831/unable-to-determine-what-cmake-generator-to-use-vs-code-windows-10/74240235#74240235

I'm now running into a problem where when I try to run the command `mingw32-make` in the build folder I get a command not found error.
My environment variable is set to the correct path I'm pretty sure: `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin`

Comment: Which make executable is there in mingw64/bin folder?